# Disable additional field "X-DevTools-Request-Id" in header when debugging (electron/axios)

Tags: cors, electron, axios

I am not sure if this is an axios or electron question.

I am developing an electron app which is communication with a IoT device using a Rest API.
The root cause of my problem is that this device is not sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` this means I can only do *simple* requests.

Example header:

```
GET /hello.json HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.100.101
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:9080
X-DevTools-Request-Id: 15299.27
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Electron/1.8.6 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:9080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
```

One requirement of such a simple request is that only certain fields are allowed in the request header.

The issue is that in debug mode the header of the request contains the additional field `X-DevTools-Request-Id`. Therefore all requests fail.

Is there a way to remove/disable this field?

(I was able to confirm that when I build and run the application the request works as expected.)